# Pass paramtes to event function

Tags: javascript

I bulid a function to event and I want to know how can I pass parameters to that function?

I use `addEventListener` method to add events
What I need is to pass the `element` variable to the function mean `this` object

For example if I use attribute method to add event I do like this:

```
 <div onclick="function(this)">
```

And then the `function` will get the div element
Now my question is how can I pass the this object to the function when I use `addEventListener`

Is there anyway to get this thing?

Comment: When adding events the funtion always receives an event argument.  That event argument has a target property.  Which is the element that caused the event to fire

Answer (score 1):

```
Blah.addEventListener(function(event){
     var element = event.target;
```

});

Posted from phone.  Please forgive

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Define your listener with a parameter, this will be an event object.
In this object you will find the triggered element.

Answer (score 0):

In an event handler, such as onclick, 'this' will automatically point to the element, where the event is triggered. You can use it inside your anonymous function.
Note: It's not a string but a HtmlElement.
Hope I have understood your question correctly.